# Re-editing an existing game

Tags: file, testing, programming-languages, edit

#### *I state that I am a beginner, (I study the basics of programming and I do not know many things), but I am a very curious guy.*

> ### So I was wondering if it's possible to take the files of a game (e.g. Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege), and modify it to your liking, obviously an offline version that only you can use.

Thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: It depends on what "modify it to your liking" means, but yes, you can read any file, change the contents of that file, and write out a new version of that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "modding" and here are the basic things you need to know:

1. You need to be a pretty good programmer/hacker to do this.
2. Some game manufacturers explicitly do not permit it and thus, in this case, anyone who does it is a hacker.
3. Some game manufacturers actively encourage it and some have even published "modding kits" to make it easier.
4. Some (most?) game manufacturers neither encourage nor specifically disallow it.
5. Except for case #3, this is not the place for these questions (google "modding <yourGame>").

Also, in case #3, either the manufacturer's support site or perhaps https://gamedev.stackexchange.com may be better places to ask this question.  However, the required programming skill/knowledge level is still pretty high.